# Is bramhacharya only for virgins? Can non virgins be a bramhachari?

Tags: sex, bramhacharya

Is it necessary for a person to be a virgin to follow brahmacharya?

Comment: brahmacharya basically means sexual continence or complete abstinence, it has nothing to do with virginity.

Comment: not necessary. there are many examples of sadhus who gave became brahmacharis after marriage